# User.IsInRole() returns false and Authorize Roles gives me an Access Denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to set up the authentication in my existing App with ASP.NET Core Identity 2.0. As I use my own database schema and classes, I have my own User and Role classes and I had to create custom UserStore/UserManager/RoleStore/RoleManager.

I declare them in my services :

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Profile().AddUserManager<CustomUserManager<User>>().AddRoleManager<CustomRoleManager>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddTransient<IUserStore<User>, UserStore>();
services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<Profile>, ProfileStore>();
services.AddTransient<UserResolverService>();
```

I implement the interface UserRoleStore in the UserStore with these methods :

```
    public Task AddToRoleAsync(User user, string roleName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        user.Profiles.Add(db.Profiles.ToList().Find(x => x.Name.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));

        db.SaveChanges();

        return Task.FromResult((object)null);
    }

    public Task RemoveFromRoleAsync(User user, string roleName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        user.Profiles.Remove(db.Profiles.ToList().Find(x => x.Name.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));

        db.SaveChanges();

        return Task.FromResult((object)null);
    }

    public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IList<string> ret = new List<string>();
        user.Profiles.ToList().ForEach(x => ret.Add(x.Name));
        return Task.FromResult(ret);
    }

    public Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(Useruser, string roleName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Profile searchRole = db.Profiles.Include(profile => profile.ProfileUsers).ToList().Find(x => x.Active && x.Name.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        return Task.FromResult(searchRole.ProfileUsers.ToList().Find(x => x.UserID == user.ID) == null ? false : true);
    }

    public Task<bool> IsInRole(User user, string roleName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    public Task<IList<Utilisateur>> GetUsersInRoleAsync(string roleName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Profile currentProfile = db.Profiles.Include(profile => profile.ProfileUsers).ThenInclude(pu => pu.User).ToList().Find(x => x.Active && x.Name.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (currentProfile == null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult((IList<User>)null);
        }

        IList<User> ret = new List<User>();
        currentProfile.ProfileUsers.ToList().ForEach(x => ret.Add(x.User));
        return Task.FromResult(ret);
    }
```

So when I try to do

```
var result1 = _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userObject, "WorkOrderViewer");
var res = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("WorkOrderViewer");
var test = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(userObject, "WorkOrderViewer");
```

It works and my user gets the choosen Role. However, when I try to set up the controller authorizations or the controls visibility in the view it doesn't work. For the controller authorization I have an access denied for exemple.

When I put this in my code :

```
var test = User.IsInRole("WorkOrderViewer");
```

It returns "false" even if I am log in the app (I try to log out and log in) and if the UserManager.IsInRoleAsync returns me "true".

I think it fails because UserManager.AddToRoleAsync() is not synchronized with User.IsInRole() but I don't know how to resolve it.
Have you an idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say you use the code `User.IsInRole` I assume you mean in a `Controller`.

[`User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.user?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in a controller is of type [`ClaimsPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=netframework-4.7.2).

And the method [`ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.isinrole?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Claims_ClaimsPrincipal_IsInRole_System_String_) has the following documentation:

> The IsInRole method checks whether an identity that this claims principal possesses contains a claim of type ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType where the value of the claim is equal to the value specified by the role parameter.

This can be confirmed by looking at the [source for ClaimsIdentity.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Security.Claims/src/System/Security/Claims/ClaimsPrincipal.cs#L507).

```
if (_identities[i].HasClaim(_identities[i].RoleClaimType, role))
```

So `User.IsInRole`is checking to see if the User has a Claim of type RoleClaimType (which defaults to "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role.").

The claim type can be configured as needed.

Comment: Nice ! It is what I need. 
How can you configure the claim type ? I think you have to create a class which implement IPrincipal and where do you declare it ? In the services configuration ?